# Rust move operation - a rookies misunderstanding

Tags: rust, move, ownership

I am a C# developer and I would like to learn Rust. I have a little question regarding "move".

According to this link: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.move.html

The following example demonstrates moving ownership of variables to another thread and claims that the data cannot be referenced in the original scope afterwards. Example code from the link:

**EXAMPLE CODE FROM RUST-LANG.ORG:**

```
let data = vec![1, 2, 3];

std::thread::spawn(move || {
    println!("captured {data:?} by value")
}).join().unwrap();

// data was moved to the spawned thread, so we cannot use it here
```

However, I have made a little test program which I would predict should fail at compile time, but it actually builds and runs:

**MY CODE:**

```
use std::io::{Error};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let mut b : i32 = 12;
    thread::spawn(move || {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(500));
        println!("HELLO {}", b);
    });
    b = 88;
    println!("HELLO {}", b);
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
    return Ok(());
}
```

**OUTPUT FROM RUNNING MY CODE:**

```
HELLO 88
HELLO 12
```

Why am I allowed to access b and set it to 88 after moving it to the thread's scope?

Built with cargo version: cargo 1.61.0 (a028ae42f 2022-04-29)

**UPDATE**

I realized that value types behave differently from reference types.

The following code does not compile - just as anticipated:

```
use std::io::{Error};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let mut b = vec![1, 2, 3];
    thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("HELLO {}", b.len());
    });
    println!("HELLO {}", b.len()); // <= This is not allowed
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
    return Ok(());
}
```

So can anyone point at any documentation that can explain this behaviour to me in a structured way?

Comment: This is just because there are some types Rust is allowed to copy implicitly, those that implement the [Copy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) trait. See the book's relevant [section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-03-derivable-traits.html#clone-and-copy-for-duplicating-values).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But as a developer, I cannot see what is going on with my bare eyes then? (whether something is cloned/copied or ownership has actually changed)

Comment: What? Do you expect Rust to require you to explicitly write every single byte copy it makes? I could understand this if you were an assembly programmer, but coming from C# you surely can understand a programming language abstracts away some of this boilerplate without notifying you. Besides, if you continue learning Rust, you'll know when Rust does this kind of things, as it's actually quite rare Rust does implicit things.

Comment: @Blackbeans no I didnt mean that I would expect to do byte copying manually. :D
It just strikes me that I am not explicitly allowing rust to do a copy of the value, so if this was a huge object I might unintentionally copy it even if all I wanted was to just move the ownership to the thread. And it scares me if this behvaiour is dictated by the fact whether the type is clonable/copyable or not.

Comment: @Chayim yes it answers my question and as a C# programmer I would never expect the entire array to be copied behind the scenes by the simple statement let b = a;

Comment: Copy can only be bitwise, which is pretty cheap on modern hardware. Still, [there's an experimental warn-by-default lint with configurable threshold about big copies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/lints/listing/warn-by-default.html#large-assignments).

Comment: I really understand why there is a need for this warn for big copies!
Thank you Chayim! It is so valuable for me that you take your time to explain thing and provide links with details!

Comment: Because C# is GCed. Do not however that LLVM may very well eliminate big copies by various ways and that in practice big copies are not a common performance pitfall in my experience. We tend to store big objects behind an indirection (reference, `Box` etc.) anyway.

Comment: Coming from C# you'll appreciate the differences between a `class` and `struct`. In C# `var a = b;` behaves differently depending on whether the type of `b` is a `class` or a `struct` or simple type.

Comment: @rodrigo well I know that class and struct will behave differently in C#. And I now know I need to be aware of how things work in Rust to avoid pitfalls.

Comment: Also, it is important to note that most types that will store "big" stuff are not necessarily `Copy`. Most of them are just `Clone`, which requires you explicitly making that copy. You can think of it this way: a type implements `Copy` often if it's cheaper than just moving a pointer around. For instance, most pointers in Rust do implement `Copy` (except for exclusive borrows, for instance), because of course when you're passing a pointer around, you don't want to pass a pointer to that pointer instead.